# Trace of a function on a bounded interval in $1$D

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a sequence of $H^{1}$ functions $f_{n} : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and I know that $\|f_{n}'\|_{L^{2}(0,1)} \le C$ where $C>0$ is independent of $n$. Is this enough to say that $|f_{n}(0)| \le C$ independently of $n$ too?

---

I know that in general for $\Omega$ Lipschitz domain we have trace theorems which tell us something like that $\|u\|_{L^{p}(\partial \Omega)} \le C_{p}\|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}$. But in our case $\partial \Omega$ is a zero measure set and I'm not really sure how to adapt those results to this case. For example I don't know how the norm on $L^{p}(\partial \Omega)$ can even make sense if $\partial \Omega$ is a zero measure set.

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, this follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(0) = f(t) - \int_0^t f'(s)ds$, so $f(0) = \int_0^1 f(t) - \int_0^t f'(s) ds dt$; you can use Holder inequality to bound this by $L^2$ norms. Incidentally this is how you prove the trace theorem in higher dimensions too, you just integrate in the remaining variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $f_n(x)=n$.

The 'measure zero' problem is no problem. The boundary of the interval is $\{0,1\}$, so that $\|u\|_{L^p(\partial\Omega)} = ( |u(0)|^p + |u(1)|^p)^{1/p}$ (for smooth $u$).

Comment: Thank you. But why is this the $L^{p}$ norm on $\{0,1\}$? Is there perhaps a reference which goes into more detail on $L^{p}$ norms on zero measure sets?

Comment: The boundary $\partial \Omega$ is always of measure zero for Lipschitz sets, independent of the dimension. The measure on the boundary of $(0,1)$ is the counting measure, i.e., the measure of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: Ah yes okay thanks!